# Поэтапное выполнение на javascript

Tags: javascript

Я хочу запрограммировать программу на javascript поэтапно.

Слева вводишь слово нажимаешь <kbd>Enter</kbd> и оно отображается справа под номером без перезагрузки страницы.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Словник</title>
  <style>
    table,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    td {
      padding: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table style="width:20%">
    <caption>Словник</caption>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#D3EDF6" align="center">
        <form name="test" method="post" action="">
          <p>
            <b>Слово:</b><br>
            <input type="text" size="40">
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
            <input type="reset" value="Очистить">
          </p>
        </form>
        </form>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">1.</td>
      <td>function</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">2.</td>
      <td>step</td>
    </tr>
    <td align="center">3.</td>
    <td>caption</td>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">4.</td>
      <td>border</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td align="center">5.</td>
      <td>table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">6.</td>
      <td>autofocus</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">7.</td>
      <td>defines</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">8.</td>
      <td>form</td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Вам надо сначала узнать, что такое *"серверном javascript"*. В вопросе у вас слишком мало деталей, на такой вопрос невозможно ответить.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko что мне надо узнать? какие детали нужни?

Comment: Нужно ли хранить список где нибудь в базе данных? Зачем вам в разметке `action="input1.php"`?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko список будет храниться в бд mysql

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko `action="input1.php"` подправил

Comment: Так в чем именно у вас проблема? Что не получается?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko я придумал задачу, хочу решить используя JavaScript, html, css, node.js. мне нужно поетапное описание решения, вроде такое називается ТЗ, что би я смог написать код.

Comment: на кнопку "Отправить" вешаете обработчик события через `addEventListener`, в котором реализуете необходимую Вам логику

Comment: ТЗ - это сама задача, а не решение. Для своей задачи ты его сформулировал как _Слева вводишь слово нажимаешь Enter и оно отображается справа под номером без перезагрузки страницы._ Поэтому не совсем понятно, что именно и в каком виде ты хочешь увидеть в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так

```js
var counter = 1; //это будет счётчик слов (номер перед словом в таблице)
var input = document.getElementById('textfield'); //достаём текстовое поле из HTML
var container = document.getElementById('content'); //достаём таблицу куда будем вставлять слова
var row; //сюда будем записывать код новой строки которую потом добавим в таблицу

function addWord() { // Функция "Добавить слово"
  //разметка таблицы и в ней переменная счётчика а также значение текстового поля
  row = '<tr><td class="num">' + counter + '.</td><td>' + input.value + '</td></tr>';
  counter++; //прибавляем 1 к счётчику слов
  input.value = ''; //обнуляем значение текстового поля
  //сохранив то что уже есть в таблице, добавляем новую строку
  container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + row; 
}

function resetTable() { // Функция "Сброс"
  //обнуляем содержимое таблицы, текстового поля и счётчик
  container.innerHTML = '';
  input.value = '';
  counter = 1;
}
```

```css
table, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
}

table { width:300px; }
    
td {
  padding: 2px;
}

td.num {
  width: 8%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <table>
    <caption>Словник</caption>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#D3EDF6" align="center">
        <form name="test" method="post" action="">
          <p>
            <b>Слово:</b><br>
            <input type="text" id="textfield" size="40">
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="button" onClick="addWord()" value="Отправить">
            <input type="button" onClick="resetTable()" value="Очистить">
          </p>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="content">
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Удачи в изучении программирования! Советую вникнуть в код, и понять как работает каждое слово в нём, вместо того чтобы просто скопипастить.

Если помог, можешь поставить плюс и выбрать ответ как лучший

Comment: `container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + row;` - не очень хорошая запись. Лучше делать через `appendChild`. А `<td>' + input.value + '</td>` - просто опасно!

Comment: Опасно писать так не экранируя теги на реальном сайте, а для учебного примера сойдёт. Решил не усложнять. Про appendChild тоже годный вариант.

Comment: *опасно писать так не экранируя теги на реальном сайте* - как вы думаете, ТС знает об этом? Он возьмет ваш ответ и напишет реальный сайт. Без `appendChild` появится новый вопрос по типу: *Почему пропадают обработчики событий после добавления новой строки?*

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko если вы выполните код, то убедитесь в том, что никуда обработчики событий не пропадают  Чтобы ТС-у писать реальный сайт, ему придётся ознакомиться с основами обеспечения web-безопасности, если для него это важно. Никто не застрахован от своих ошибок. Если я в ответе буду заботиться о не касающихся непосредственно вопроса аспектов, это лишь введёт ТС-а в заблуждение, т.к. кода будет гораздо больше...

Comment: Лучше больше кода, но что бы он был правильный, без дыр и багов, не находите? Если в таблице будут обработчики, навешанные через `addEventListener`, то при изменении `innerHTML` они пропадут.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko лучше - решать задачу отталкиваясь от её условий. Если стоит вопрос сделать учебный пример, сдать его и удалить - делаем просто. Стоит вопрос сделать серьёзный сайт, присутствуют addEventListener внутри table - продумываем аспекты безопасности, учитываем остальные нюансы. В целом вы правы конечно, стоит думать об этом, но я привык решать задачу в зависимости от её потребностей, и к примеру когда пишу интерфейсы для себя не заморачиваюсь насчёт излишеств.

Comment: @Rikky нет ви не помогли. я не опитний пользователь сайта и не прошу за меня решать мои задачи.

Comment: @eko комментарии к коду даны, если я терминами выражаться начну вы меня просто не поймёте............

Comment: Ну, у нас разные подходы. Я стараюсь всегда писать как можно лучше (хотя, конечно, это не отменяет глупые ошибки) с точки зрения качества\читаемости\производительности - именно в таком порядке :) Даже когда пишу для себя скрипт в tampermonkey.

Comment: @Rikky а кем ви меня считаете и тем более себя, что я не смогу понять!!